# Event.key não funciona

Tags: python, pygame

Então eu estou tentando fazer a tela ficar *fullscreen* no pygame, só que o `event.key` não funciona.

Segue o erro:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Ailtinho/Desktop/Scirpts-Python/Jogo em python/Jogo.py", line 29, in 
>     if event.key == pygame.K_f:
> AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'.
> ```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o código inteiro:

```py
import pygame

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Joguinho')
altura, largura = 90, 60
move_right = False
move_left = False
dino_pos = [100, 75]
comands = pygame.key.get_pressed()

while True:
    window.fill((211, 211, 211))

    if move_right:
        dino_pos[0] += 4
    if move_left:
        dino_pos[0] -= 4

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type  == pygame.K_f:
            window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                move_right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                move_left = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                move_right = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                move_left = False

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

O `event.key` só esta disponível quando os eventos forem do tipo "teclado", quando o `event.type` for igual a `KEYDOWN` ou `KEYUP` por exemplo

Você esta tentando executar ele a qualquer momento em qualquer tipo de evento e o `pygame.event.get()` pega diversos eventos, não só de teclado, logo teu script tentou acessar o .key em um evento que não é do mesmo tipo, ocasionando o erro, mude para:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()

    if event.type  == pygame.K_f:
        window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        else:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                move_right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                move_left = True
    if event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key == K_RIGHT:
            move_right = False
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            move_left = False
```